# Glow text + text outline in CSS (already using text-shadow for glow)

Tags: css, css-animations

So I've hit a bit of a brick wall. I am using a keyframes glow for some text, but I also need to apply a text outline as well. Is this possible in CSS?

Please see attached. The text is green so finding a color to complement it well was hard enough. I demoed a few things in Excel and found what I like but not sure how to recreate it in CSS.

Here is what I want:

[image]
http://www.flickr.com/photos/68814612@N05/8560198200/

And this is the code I am using so far:

```
.metric {
    font-size: 240%;
    font-family:Arial Narrow;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#138200;

    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #92d050, 1px -1px 0 #92d050, -1px 1px 0 #92d050, 1px 1px 0 #92d050;
    -webkit-animation-name: glow;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}


@-webkit-keyframes glow {

    0% { text-shadow: 0 0 4px green; }
    50% {text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(19,130,0, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(19,130,0, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(19,130,0, 0.6),0 0 15px rgba(19,130,0, 0.6) ;}
    100% { text-shadow: 0 0 4px green; }
        }
```

Comment: I suppose you could add another element and place it under the first one, and apply the effects to the new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for posterity, here is what I did in response to Jeff's proposal above:

http://jsfiddle.net/Osceana/cNYZa/

HTML:

```
<div id="Percentage">
    <div class="metric">98.3%</div>
    <div class="metric2">98.3%</div>
</div>
```

Then I just set the keyframes glow in CSS:

```
.metric {
    position: absolute;

    font-size: 37pt;
    font-family:Segoe UI Light;
    color:#138200;

    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #92d050, 1px -1px 0 #92d050, -1px 1px 0 #92d050, 1px 1px 0 #92d050;
    -webkit-animation-name: glow;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}


@-webkit-keyframes glow {

    0% { text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(19,130,0, 0.7); }
    50% {text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(19,130,0, 0.7), 0 0 20px rgba(19,130,0, 1), 0 0 20px rgba(19,130,0, 1),0 0 20px rgba(19,130,0, 1),0 0 20px rgba(19,130,0, 1),0 0 20px rgba(19,130,0, 1), 0 0 30px rgba(19,130,0, 1);}
    100% { text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(19,130,0, 0.5)/*0 0 4px green*/; }
        }


.metric2 {
    position:absolute;

    font-size: 37pt;
    font-family:Segoe UI Light;
    color:#138200;

    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #92d050, 1px -1px 0 #92d050, -1px 1px 0 #92d050, 1px 1px 0 #92d050;

}
```